# Deploying / Publishing Azure Durable HTTP Function App to Azure - Execution hanging on first Activity Trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I've been trying to deploy my Azure Durable HTTP Function app to my Azure resource group which I seem to have successfully done, to a degree at least.

When I go to the 'functions' tab
[image]
and click [image] to get the execution link, it kicks off the HTTP Trigger which calls the Durable Orchestrator which seems to 'schedule' the first Activity method in my Orchestrator, but not even the first line prints which is just a log. It printed ONE time which I found extremely strange as I had only restarted the Function App and ran it again.

There are so many ID's (processId, instanceId, operationId, etc) and so many other interfaces / diagnostic tools that I'm over-inundated with info and don't know how to make heads or tails of what's happening here.

I have App insights hooked up and the CPU will cap out at 100% as if the function app is running but nothing is happening.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Share your actual function code.

Comment: Ok - the reason I didn’t provide it initially is because there’s too much PII so I was hoping it was a deployment configuration issue or something, but I will go through in the morning and clean out the details. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue was quite simple after all.

My environment variables in the local.settings.json weren't automatically migrated to the Azure environment after publishing as I assumed they would.

After manually entering them in the Azure 'configuration' blade, everything works fine.